# how to detect GPS is on or off using cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I am creating mobile app which uses geolocation plugin and I want show popup to enable GPS when GPS is turned off. How to detect whether GPS is on or off and how to show location setting to on GPS?

Comment: Do you want a GPS listener?

Comment: https://github.com/BastienL/GPSDetector

Comment: how to add this plugin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using the following Cordova Plugin:
https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin

Add the plugin:

```
ionic plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic
```

Check for GPS whether it is enabled or not as below,

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

If GPS is not enabled, Open Location settings as below,

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
```

Complete code:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(successCallback, errorCallback);
function successCallback(res){
  console.log("Location is " + (res ? "Enabled" : "not Enabled"));
  !res ? cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings() : '';
}
function errorCallback(err){
  console.log("Error: "+JSON.stringify(err));
}
```